# Changing date in a dataframe to specifc formats in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I have a dataframe df. I need to change the format of the dataframe as shown below with examples. How to achieve this?

Input

```
Date            id      .   .   .   .   
1947-01-01      1       .   .   .   .
1947-04-01      2       .   .   .   .
1947-08-01      3       .   .   .   .
.
....
```

Output

```
    Date        id      .   .   .   .   
    Q1-1947     1       .   .   .   .
    Q2-1947     2       .   .   .   .
    Q3-1947     3       .   .   .   .
    .
    ....
```

Similarly, how could I get this

```
        Date           id       .   .   .   .   
        M01-1947        1       .   .   .   .
        M04-1947        2       .   .   .   .
        M08-1947        3       .   .   .   .
        .
        ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For month, I used what was mentioned by @Alon Alexander

```
df['Date'].dt.strftime("M%m-%Y")
```

For Quarter,

```
df['Date'] = (df['Date'].dt.to_period('Q').dt.strftime('Q%q-%Y'))
#df.rename(columns = {'Date': 'Date_Quarter'}, inplace = True)
##Commented portion is optional, if you want to rename the column
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the months, check [Python's `datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for how to format the desired strings.

You can get the wanted behavior with:

```py
df['Date'].dt.strftime("M%m-%Y")
```

For the quarters, try using `apply` and calculating the quarter by hand.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure out quarterly part, but am having to index the column without which it does not work
Here's the code
       `df = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.to_period('Q')).mean()
        df.index = df.index.strftime('Q%q-%y')`

Any alternate way to do this? Please suggest